# LDAP Groups and Git Source Code Hosting

Tags: git, ldap, self-hosting

We want to host our own repositories in our Company. We need LDAP support especially with Groups. So I want that User from Group A can't access Projects of Group B. Not even Read it, if it is not allowed.

I also don't want to use https. So best is, if the user logs into the webpage (LDAP login) and uploads his SSH key. After that he should be able to see only projects/repositories for his LDAP group or for all Groups he is in.

Thank you for Your Help!
Joerg

Comment: Gitorious has LDAP auth, and is really neat.  It doesn't support LDAP groups, but I'm sure there are folks that would be über grateful if you added it... http://gitorious.org

Comment: I know they would, but till now, I don't think I can write such a feature!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a helpful solution. I used [Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) and wrote my own script. Gitolite allows you to use a script to ask the LDAP/AD for the groups. With this [Website](https://github.com/gvalkov/gitolite-sshkey-form) you can create your own SSH-Key form. For browsing the repos, you can use gitweb with gitolite! Besides the SSH-Key-Form I got everything is up & running.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an authorization layer like Gitolite, which would then be able to get [group information](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/doc/big-config.html#_storing_usergroup_information_outside_gitolite_like_in_LDAP_) through [LDAP scripts](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/tree/pu/contrib/ldap).
The native way of accessing the repo managed by Gitolite would remain SSH.

> Large sites often have LDAP servers that already contain user and group information, including group membership details.
>   Such sites may prefer that gitolite just pick up that info instead of having to redundantly put it in gitolite's config file.
>
> All you need is a script that, given a username, queries your LDAP or similar server, and returns a space-separated list of all the groups she is a member of.
>   If an invalid user name is sent in, or the user is valid but is not part of any groups, it should print nothing.

Comment: do you know any sites, which I can use on top of gitolite?